# FreeMat alternative to MatLab's findobj()

Tags: matlab, freemat

Is there an equivalent function in FreeMat? I can't seem to find one and the documentation is poorly organised.

Any recommendations for work-arounds?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that helps, but I am not using this function in Matlab either. I always organise my objects in a list that is either stored in a global workspace or passed around other to objects. 
So what you could do is create an Object like a list that has a search and add function. Put it in global scope and make it a singleton (I know, friends don't let friends write singletons). This way you can find all you add to this list easily.

You might want to check out the "service locator" pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern

I think the findobj() function in MATLAB does someting similar.